# Tools to identify lexicalization

Tags: morphology, lexicon, compounds

Is there any tests or morphological test which can help to identify whether an expression is lexicalised or not? For example, whether some compounds are processed through morphological processes or stored in the lexicon?

Comment: Most likely different people use different processes; after all, everybody has a different set of data to account for in their internal processing schemata.

Comment: Productivity can be used as a guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are psycholinguistic test that can help you with this. A lexicalized element should be more easily accessed by the speaker, and the reaction times should be lower than parsing a sentence. There should also be some phonetic reduction: if the language has word boundaries these should have or be in the process of disappearing, and the word should be losing phonetic material.

You could also test for frequency for indications of lexicalization, but not concrete proof. I would say you need all of these to conclude that an expression has lexicalized.

Some morphological test would be to see if the word can use nominal morphology. This is however problematic since it only works for other parts of speech lexicalizing, and not the lexicalization of compound nouns or things like that. But if a verb-noun, or short phrase or sentence can start building plurals, diminutives, declensions, etc, then it probably has lexicalized to some degree.